# Redirect ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Boas a todos. Estou a tentar redirecionar de uma Actionresult para outra e já tentei de tudo sempre sem sucesso. Neste momento encontro-me com o seguinte código:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
            public ActionResult Index_GA_ER(string tkn)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Eresults_Base");
            }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Menu()
        {           
            var menuOptions = Session.GetDataFromSession<List<Menu>>(StoreManagerKeys.Menus);
            string tkn = "";
            string a = "Eresults_MenuOption_";

                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["generateInterfeatures"] != "true" || menuOptions != null)
                {
                    foreach (var button in menuOptions)
                    {
                        string b = RemoveDiacritics(button.Description).Replace(" ", "_");

                        button.MenuClass = a + b;
                    }

                    return PartialView(menuOptions);
                }
            return Index_GA_ER(tkn);
        }
```

Para a qual tenho o erro

***Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.***

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: dá uma olhada no seu actionfilter se tem isso
[ActionFilters.RequireHttps(RequireSecure = false)]

caso sim muda pra true tente de novo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015833/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions-after-setting-the-sit

Comment: O erro acontece no em qual linha, quando retorna a partial ou no método "Index_GA_ER"?

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece pois o atributo [`ChildActionOnly`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/ee728633(v=vs.118)) está fazendo com que essa `Action` *Menu* não possa ser acessada a não ser através de uma `View` filha e bloqueando os redirecionamentos (como a própria mensagem de erro diz), isso quer dizer que essa sua `Action`pode somente retornar conteúdo, e não redirecionamentos.

Você pode remover o atributo (visto que se você quer redirecionar, não faz sentido ter ele no método).